# Mysql on duplicate update not working?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

`movie_title` is a unique column.  I want to update columns on duplicate.  There are no errors in the query.

```
foreach($array['data'] as $row) {

        $movie_title = $row[0];
        $time_published = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($row[2]));
        $language = $row[3];
        $views = $row[4];
        $active = $row[6];
        $type = $row[7];
        $checked = $row[8];
        $category = $row[9];
        $rating = $row[10];
        $subtitle = $row[12];
        $visitor_views = $row[18];

        if($visitor_views!=0) {
            $view_array[] = $visitor_views;
        }

        $movie_title = explode("-",$movie_title);

        $movie_title = trim($movie_title[0]);

          $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO movies (movie_title,time_published,language,views,visitor_views,active,type,checked,category,rating,subtitle) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active=active,category=category,views=views,visitor_views=visitor_views,checked=checked,subtitle=subtitle,rating=rating,type=type,language=language",
            $movie_title,$time_published,$language,$views,$visitor_views,$active,$type,$checked,$category,$rating,$subtitle));




    }
```

This is how the query looks

```
INSERT INTO movies (movie_title,time_published,language,views,visitor_views,active,
    type,checked,category,rating,subtitle)
VALUES
    ('Bodyguard','2016-12-17 06:54:26','1','2091','15',
    '1','0','0','Feature Film ','3.66','Bodyguard.vtt')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    active=active,category=category,views=views,visitor_views=visitor_views,
    checked=checked,subtitle=subtitle,rating=rating,type=type,language=language
```

Why aren't any of the columns being updated?

Comment: Is a new record being inserted instead?  The obvious thing to ask is whether `movie_title` actually has a unique index on it (or is a primary key)?  Because it not, then your code won't do what you want.

Comment: Yes, movie_title does have unique index.  The primary key is id.

Comment: And you _certain_ that `Bodyguard` was already in the table?  Then, after the insert, did you have _two_ records with the `Bodyguard` title?

Comment: Bodyguard already exists in the table.  There is only 1 record after insert.

Comment: OK...and are you also certain that no update is happening?

Comment: I've narrowed the query down to a simple insert `$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO movies_test (movie_title) 
  VALUES
  ($movie_title)");` and nothing is being inserted.

Comment: Check the answers below.  Your syntax is off (an update is happening).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this solves the issues but perhaps it should be something like this:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active = VALUES(active), category = VALUES(category)..
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `col_name = VALUES(col_name)`, otherwise you are just saying "set x = x".

```
... 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
active=VALUES(active),category=VALUES(category),views=VALUES(views),...
```